# How to remove HTML right margin when printing with fixed size body?

Tags: html, css, printing

Using the following code, which setup the HTML page (the body) to A4 size:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@page {
  margin: 0;
}

body, html { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}

body {
  height: 842px;
  width: 595px;
}

section {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <section >
    <div style="float:left;height:60px">x</div>
    <div style="float:right;height:60px">y</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    test
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

It will remove all the margins except the right one.

How to remove the right margin when printing using the A4 page settings applied to the body to dimension the page?

Comment: Please be specific. Do you want to _add_ a right-margin ?

Comment: @Allan The title and message says, how to remove the margin when printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css sheet for printer:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printing.css" media="print">
```

And put all modifications for printing only in there.

EDIT:

Or use the media query like this:

```
@media print { 
 body { 
    margin:0;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Use this in the example code, add `body {margin:0;}` to `@media print` and  it will still show a right margin when printing.

Comment: @RedDragon Do you shared the entire code in your question or just a fragment?

Comment: @RedDragon you forgot to close your <head> tag, maybe its causing this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I forgot to close the head but it won't change the result. The code is complete, all in the provided sample.

Comment: @RedDragon maybe if you use a 100% width it will takes all the space. I don't see any margin when I use a jsfiddle.

Comment: I need to use a fixed width, because when the browser window gets redimensioned I need the report to show up in the exact same way all the time.

Comment: @RedDragon I meant for print only but i guess it has to be the same too. How do see that the margin right is there? You are printing it? Did you tried to float right to see if it's a margin or an empty blank?